# Iterating over date ranges in Python for GA API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

As you can tell I'm new to python, and struggling with the correct way/syntax to iterate over date ranges in my Google Analytics API call. The master function iterates over specific Website View IDs already (I have it loop through the 'client_id', but I'm wondering what the correct way to have it iterate over date ranges would be/where I need to put it in my code.

Right now I am running it using the GA Date Dimension to get daily results, but I also need to run it for MTD, 7 Day Rolling, and 30 Day rolling iterations. Here is a sample the code I am using.

```
def APmain(client_id):

    base_df = pd.DataFrame()
    columns = traffic_columns
    start_date = datetime.strptime(master_startdate , '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(master_enddate , '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    filters = 'ga:screenResolution!=0x0'

    print('Running Google Analytics Report.')
    
    
    #change based the type and number of dimensions pulled. These are set 
    dimensions = 'ga:'+(',ga:'.join(columns[:3]))
    metrics = 'ga:'+(',ga:'.join(columns[3:]))
    
    results = analytics_get_report(client_id, str(start_date), str(end_date), dimensions, metrics, filters)
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=columns)

    df['view_id'] = client_id
    df['filter_type'] = 'New'
    df['dimension'] = 'SourceMedium'
    df['DateType'] = 'Daily'
    base_df = base_df.append(df)

    base_df = base_df.applymap(str)
    base_df = base_df[base_df.date != '(other)'] #remove if date column has '(other)' as a value
    base_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(base_df['date'], format='%Y%m%d') #format date
    
    # Powershell output
    print(base_df.head())

    #bigquery output
    base_df.to_gbq(
        '', #dataset name + table name
        '', #project name
        chunksize=10000,
        reauth=False,
        if_exists='append',
        credentials=credentials
        )
```

I have a variables names 'master_startdate' and 'master_enddate' where I define the date range I have it pull data for currently. I've messed around with something like this but can't get it to work correctly, but I feel like I'm on the right track and/or thinking about it correctly.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import calendar

cal= calendar.Calendar()
wholeyear= range(0,365)
master_start_date= '2019-01-01'
start_date= datetime.strptime(master_start_date , '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date2= datetime.strptime(end_date , '%Y-%m-%d').date()

for x in wholeyear:
    end_date = start_date + (timedelta(days=1)*x)
    print(end_date)

    pass
    start_date2= datetime.date.today()
    start_date2= datetime.date(end_date2.year(),end_date2.month(),1)
    print(start_date2)
```

Any help for a beginner here would be greatly appreciated!